# jQuery Event Delegation input type keyup blur

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

```
$('#item_code_wrapper').on('keyup blur', '#item_code', function(){

            if( $(this).val() != ""){

                $.ajax({
                    url : "../item/code/" + $(this).val(),
                    success: function(data){

                        if (data.success == 'false') {
                            $('#item_description option').removeAttr('selected');
                        }else{
                            $('#item_description option:eq(' + data.item_id + ')').attr('selected', true);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        });
```

This one works if I copy and paste the code. It points to the option with the item id and it also remove the selected if data success is false. But then again, If I manually type item code and has a matching id it changes the option to selected but it doesn't point to that particular option.

Comment: Use `.prop('selected', false);` and `.prop('selected', true);` instead

Comment: It works like a charm buddy. Thanks.